# JAVA Calling members (other class type) of inherited class from other package

Tags: java

I'm new to JAVA and im trying to understand how inheritance works.
I have 3 classes:

```
package dziedziczenie2;


public class Kobieta {

    protected Oczy Eyes = new Oczy();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Kobieta x = new Kobieta();
        System.out.println(x.Eyes); // blue
        x.Eyes.kolor = "red";
        System.out.println(x.Eyes); // red
    }

}

class Oczy{
    public String kolor = "blue";
    public String toString(){
        return kolor;
    }
}
```

other package:

```
package dziedziczenie;

import dziedziczenie2.Kobieta;

public class Ania extends Kobieta{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ania x = new Ania();
        System.out.println(x.Eyes); // blue
        x.Eyes.kolor = "red"; // type Oczy not visable
    }

}
```

My questiong is, why i cant change Eye.kolor in Ania class simply my typing x.Eyes.kolor.

I know that Oczy is not public, but i can use its toString method somehow.
**EDIT: Why i can use its toSting method and i cant use its member?**

Do I have to make a method in Kobieta that will interact with Oczy member for me every time i want to interact with Oczy member from other package?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Either that or make class `Oczy` public so that it is visible outside of package `dziedziczenie2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class Oczy has access modifier "default" which is accessible only in the package "dziedziczenie2" n not in package "dziedziczenie".

> 1) Option:

You may simply create a file Oczy.java with declaring public class Oczy and u r done.

> 2) Option:

You may declare public static class Oczy in the class Kobieta like this.

```
public class Kobieta {
  // ur code
  public static class Oczy {
    // ur code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Eyes` is of type `Oczy` which has default visibility, since it has no access modifier. You can only access its members in the same package it's declared in, even if those are public.

> Do I have to make a method in Kobieta that will interact with Oczy
>   member for me every time i want to interact with Oczy member from
>   other package?

You can do that or you can move the `Oczy` to its own compilation unit (`.java` file) and make it `public`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are expecting `Eyes` to be inherited to `Ania` class.
Because in inheritance attributes are not inherited like methods. `Eyes` is attribute of `Kobieta` class so when `Ania` extends `Kobieta` it dont inherit it.

Comment: The `Eyes` field is `protected`.  It is accessible from `Ania`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes but I believe OP wants to access it in same way he is doing in `Kobieta` class.

Comment: It's not accessing `Eyes` that is the problem, it's accessing `kolor`.